# Richfaces fileupload - perform name check on 'add'

Tags: jsf, file-upload, richfaces

I would like to perform a check on the name of a file being uploaded via richfaces fileupload component. I would like to check this as soon as the user selects the file. A file with a wrong name, should not appear in the list, and an alert() should be called specifying the filename was not correct.

Is there a way to check the add event, and to interrupt it when the filename is not correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ypu can use onAdd function or in the richface you can use the filesubmit event in your ajax listener:

```
<rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadBean.listener}" id="upload" acceptedTypes="jpg, gif, png, bmp"
        ontyperejected="alert('Only JPG, GIF, PNG and BMP files are accepted');" maxFilesQuantity="5">
        <a4j:ajax event="filesubmit" execute="@none" render="info" />
```

Before uploading the file filesubmit event fires. So you can check what you want on there. Refer this article [Richfaces HTML documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_3_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html_single/#sect-Component_Reference-Rich_inputs-richfileUpload).

Comment: At the time I asked this question, these attributes did not exist yet. However, it seems your answer is a correct answer to my question now, so I'll accept it :-)

Comment: Hi MacDaddy, Can you explain how do I use the output of event 'filesumit' in stopping upload to happen. I tried your snippet and it still uploads the files.

Comment: I didn't get your question.. What is exactly wanted to do?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but you would need to write your own JavaScript function to check that. You could use onupload event to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

you can use onadd event, if you are using RF3.3